# Adding exectuable directory to path has no effect

Tags: kali-linux

I have a program called "spotbugs" that I would like to be able to run globally on my machine.
It resides in a directory that I have, and i dependant on other files in the same directory. (it's the one called "spotbugs", here)

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin]
└─$ ls
addMessages        copyBuggySource  experimental  filterBugs           mineBugHistory   rejarForAnalysis    spotbugs2     unionBugs
computeBugHistory  defectDensity    fb            findbugs-msv         printAppVersion  setBugDatabaseInfo  spotbugs.bat  xpathFind
convertXmlToText   deprecated       fbwrap        listBugDatabaseInfo  printClass       spotbugs            spotbugs.ico
```

If you google around for this, the most common answer is that it should be added to my path.

So Go through the following steps:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin]
└─$ $PATH
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
                                                                                                                                        
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin]
└─$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/kali/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin                                                                     127 ⨯
                                                                                                                                        
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin]
└─$ $PATH                                                    
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/kali/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin
                                                                                                                                        
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin]
└─$ cd ..                                                                                                                         127 ⨯
                                                                                                                                        
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2]
└─$ spotbugs  
zsh: permission denied: spotbugs
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2]
└─$ sudo spotbugs
sudo: spotbugs: command not found
```

So this has no effect on anything, I am not able to run the executable anywhere other than when standing in it's directory.

HOw else can I make it glboally available?

Comment: It doesn't say that the file is not there. It says that you don't have permissions. What's the output of `ls -l ~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin/spotbugs`?

Comment: Well, it says permission denied, what does `ls -l ~/Downloads/spotbugs-4.4.2/bin/spotbugs` output ? Is it executable ? if spotbugs is a shell script what do the first few lines look like ?

Comment: I had forgotten to put the last line in. It's edited now

Comment: i don't see the output of `ls -l` that @XTian and I requested.

Comment: `sudo` reset the `$PATH` to a trusted and limited value. Then, the `command not found` error should be expected.

Comment: Looks like you need to `chmod +x spotbugs`